# Display record based on primary key entered by users Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use a button to retrieve a specific record based on a primary key entered by users without adding new record.

I created a form bounded to a table to allow users to enter new records. The primary key of the table is SECID. Addition, deletion and edition are allowed in the form.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub btnGet_Click()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

    rst.FindFirst "SECID = '" & Me.SECID & " '"

End Sub
```

I expect that after SECID being entered, selected record will be displayed on the screen. But nothing happens.

Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: RecordsetClone is precisely that... a clone object.  It is not the primary recordset which is bound to the form.  Add this line to the end `If Not rst.NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = rst.bookmark`

Comment: You could technically substitute `RecordsetClone` for `Recordset`, but if the `FindFirst` call fails, it would end up resetting the Form to the last record... perhaps not the desired behavior.

Comment: @CPerkins, I added If Not rst.NoMatch Then Me.Bookmark = rst.bookmark to the end, but encountered run-time error '3022' which is about primary key violation. Me.Bookmark = rst.bookmark is highlighted in yellow. Addition and edition are allowed in this form, does it cause the problem?

Comment: The cause of that error should have nothing to do with this code.  When you attempt to move to a new record, an attempt is made to automatically save the current record.  Something else on your form is trying to store duplicate values to your primary key.  By the way, you have single quotes around Me.SECID which indicates it is a string.  If it is a Long Integer (or Autonumber field), then it does not need quotes and might even cause unexpected results.

Comment: @CPerkins,thanks for the explanation.  I think the problem is because me.secid textbox is bounded to data source, so when I change the value of it, access tries to change the record. I should create another unbounded textbox as filter to jump to the record I want. But that will make my UI look bad. Me. SECID is a text field.

Comment: It doesn't have to look bad and in fact that is how I design most of my primary forms.  Many applications and web pages function like this.  It actually seems awkward to have the same control be both a search and a display field.  I have a normal bound field for the primary key and set Locked = True for the control to avoid the problem you're experiencing.  For me, I put a textbox labeled "Search for ID" or "Search for Name" in the form footer with a unique background color and border, for example, then have similar code to yours for implementing the search.

Comment: It's possible to have a field act both as an indicator and as a search box by using an unbound control, then updating it in Form_Current event, etc.  But to be truly useful and intuitive, it needs to correctly handle cases when a search fails otherwise it is confusing and misleading. For instance, if it leaves the failed value in the textbox, it might seem to the user that the current record is the searched-for record. But if it resets the field back to the current record value, that can also be very annoying since it eliminates the possibility of a simple edit before searching again.